# php strtok alternative to split strings

Tags: php

`strtok` has been recommended and preferred over other function such as explode when string have to split as it returns only one piece at a time, with each subsequent call returning the next piece.

But here, is it better to replace `strtok` (first-way) with second way? I keep priority to second one, because it is less coded, but don't know about performance and memory consumption in large string. Which one is best ?

```
$stdt='4-50';
```

**First way using strtok**

```
$stdt_cut = strtok( $stdt, '-' );
$stdt_final = strtok( '' );
echo $stdt_final;
//output is 50
```

**Second way using substr and strstr**

```
echo substr(strstr($stdt, '-'), 1)
//output is 50
```

Comment: [`strtok()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) uses hidden global variable to keep its state between two calls. This makes impossible to use it to parse two or more strings on the same time. It is faster than `substr()`+`strstr()` and probably similar regarding the memory consumption. Unless you are processing a very large string (megabytes), [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) produces the easiest to read and understand code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prototype of strstr is:

```
string strstr ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, bool $before_needle = FALSE ] )
```

and the function

> Returns part of haystack string starting from and including the first
>   occurrence of needle to the end of haystack.

so based on this:`$stdt='4-50';`
 at this step:`strstr($stdt, '-');`

you already have '-50';
so you can effectively use:

`substr(strstr($stdt, '-'), 1);`

or

`ltrim(strstr($stdt, '-'),'-');`

But a really fast way in you case could be  as  strpos is stated  to be less consuming and more faster than strstr and also because you use all the same substr:

```
substr($stdt,strpos($stdt,'-')+1)
```